# Cshtml button alignment top and bottom

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have 3 buttons in a popup form. I want to align first button at the top and other two together at the second line/row. I have implemented the below method and failed where top button is top but not wrap the content and two buttons at the bottom mesh together. How i can manipulate the buttons?

This is my html:

```
<div>
<table>
<tr><td colspan="2"><a href="#" id="acc_popup" data-role="button" data-rel="back" data-theme="c">Btn1</a></td></tr>
<tr>
<td><a href="#" id="acc_popup" data-role="button" data-rel="back" data-theme="c">Btn2</a></td>
<td><a href="#" id="acc_popup" data-role="button" data-rel="back" data-theme="c">Btn3</a></td>
</tr>
</table> 
</div>
```

How they look like:

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: You should post the CSS that you are using as that is what is causing you formatting issues. Basically the first button is taking a whole row in the table because it's in a `tr` tag while the other two buttons are in `td` tags.

Comment: i havent used css. its html alone. and when i insert td for top button then it gets smaller only and place above exactly `btn2`. thanks btw

Comment: There is CSS that is diffidently being loaded somewhere as the default code would look something like the following: http://jsfiddle.net/HLkUD/. What are you using to develop this? Also you can try and add `colspan="2"` to the top td so that it takes up two columns.

Comment: i have added colspan="2" and updated my answer. can u check pls?

Answer (score 1):

The main problem you're having here is that you are trying to apply styles from the `#acc_popup` CSS selector to multiple elements on the same page.

`id` tags need to be unique in the DOM structure, and multiple occurrences of them will cause your styles or scripts to apply only to the first occurrence of the id.

Swap the id for a class.

In the HTML:

```
<td><a href="#" class="acc_popup" data-role="button" data-rel="back" data-theme="c">Btn</a></td>
```

In the CSS:

```
.acc_popup {
   //styles go here
}
```

**Edit:**

Now since you've informed us you're not doing this with css. This should do what you want.

Wrap the first button in a `<td>` and add `colspan=2` to that element. If it isn't blatantly clear, this makes the table cell span 2 columns instead of the default 1.

```
<div>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2"><a href="#" id="acc_popup" data-role="button" data-rel="back" data-theme="c">Btn1</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="#" id="acc_popup" data-role="button" data-rel="back" data-theme="c">Btn2</a></td>
      <td><a href="#" id="acc_popup" data-role="button" data-rel="back" data-theme="c">Btn3</a></td>
   </tr>
  </table> 
</div>
```

Comment: yes correct  i use standard styles from `#acc_popup` but i have either tried some `CSS` styles as well which im failed. do you have any suggestion for css inline?

Comment: i updated my question after implemented ur suggestions. its like we re almost there but need to fill according to gaps right and left

Comment: So you need it to take up the whole container (the green part)?

Comment: yes @pjmil116 exactly. it should be something with top %100 and bottoms %50 %50